# Error react native when run react-native run-android

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

When i want run react-native run-android command i see

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'reactNativeCliTest'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3)
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.2.3/gradle-core-2.2.3.jar'.
>   >     Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out:
>   >     connect
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 26.854 secs Could not install the app on the device, read
>   the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I use genymotion  .

thank you ...

Comment: Try using a proxy/vpn. If you're in a blocked country like Iran, then you can't build without using one.

Answer (score 1):

RN is trying to download a new version of gradle and get error code 443. This error is related to misconfigured system files in your windows operating system. It's not related to react native and you can search about fix this error in your system. 
as an experience, you have to use hotspot shield or strong vpn to download from jcenter in iran!

this link may help you: http://www.wiki-errors.com/err.php?wiki=443